# Android : Align textviews in a listview

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have a listvew which has three textviews. I am not sure how to align them so that the output looks like:

```
abcded   -> xxxx              aaa
ddd      -> qqq               bbb
alkdladd -> hzhdl             ccc
```

Rather than what I am currently getting:

```
abcded -> xxxx                aaa
ddd -> qqq                    bbb
alkdladd -> hzhdl             ccc
```

The textviews in first row are :

```
textview1 = abcded
textview2 = -> xxxx
textview3 = aaa
```

The problem is with the alignment of textview in the middle. How can I go about doing it?

Comment: Hey, is "abcded   -> xxxx" the string that goes in the listview or is it 3 separate listviews?

Comment: @jvrodrigues - Hi, just edited the question.

Comment: @zgc7009 fully answered your question! Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have is to simply have your list item layout contain a `LinearLayout` and use weights. Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"> />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/center_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize ="end" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This makes the assumption that you only want your text in each view to be a single line. It will ellipsize (add three dots to the end) of any Strings that would otherwise wrap to another line. You can mess with the weights as you need to to get the look you want.

There may be other ways using something like `RelativeLayout`s or something, but weights (I have found) are the best way to guarantee alignment in your apps universally.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I want the text in each of them to be in a single line. I will try what you have suggested and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @user2260040 I have done quite a few layouts like you are trying to do so if you run into any issues just let me know, should be able to solve any issues you may come across.